# Variables don't pass from main function to other functions

Tags: python, function, oop, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a web scraper. I made a function that returns the cookies and headers. For simplicity on my code example it's a constant value and I only set headers but normally it gets the values with a request.  The other function gets image links from the website but for that it needs headers. I define headers  on my main function then I call the get_photos function but it says headers aren't defined.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
s = requests.session()

def login():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'}
    return headers

def get_photos():
    response = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/111px-Example.jpg', headers=headers)
    return response

def main():
    """That's where the magic happens."""
    headers = login()
    print(get_photos())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/archie/evip/example.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/archie/evip/example.py", line 16, in main
    print(get_photos())
  File "/home/archie/evip/example.py", line 9, in get_photos
    response = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/111px-Example.jpg', headers=headers)
NameError: name 'headers' is not defined
```

Comment: Of course, there is no `headers` anywhere in scope in `get_photos`. The simplest thing is to pass `headers` to `get_photos` as an argument

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the headers variable to `get_photos(headers)`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
s = requests.session()

def login():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'}
    return headers

def get_photos(headers):
    response = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/111px-Example.jpg', headers=headers)
    return response

def main():
    """That's where the magic happens."""
    print(get_photos(login()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your code to have `headers` in scope for `get_photos` method

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
s = requests.session()

def login():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'}
    return headers

def get_photos(headers):
    response = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/111px-Example.jpg', headers=headers)
    return response

def main():
    """That's where the magic happens."""
    headers = login()
    print(get_photos(headers))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Check the `get_photos` method call in `main`.

---

This happens due to something called [scope of variables](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-variable-scope/#:%7E:text=The%20scope%20of%20a%20variable,before%20let%27s%20revise%20python%20Syntax.&text=Also%2C%20the%20duration%20for%20which,is%20called%20its%20%27lifetime%27.).